# Teamcity ignores project contexts configured in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have a solution which contains six projects.

Four of the projects are class libraries, and the other two are a WPF application, and a Windows Service. The later two projects have a project configuration called 'Test' - all of the class libraries do not have this configuration, only the standard 'Debug' and 'Release' configs.

I have added a *solution* configuration called 'Test', and in the Configuration Manager, I have copied the settings from Release, so that all of the class libraries are built in the Release configuration, and the WPF and Windows Services are built with the 'Test' configuration.

The solution build works fine in Visual Studio (2010), however, when I configure a Visual Studio (sln) runner in TeamCity 7, it ignores these settings, and attempts to build all projects using a 'Test' configuration, and of course it can't find this config for the class libraries.

Is there any way to tell TeamCity to use these project contexts that are stored in the solution file?

I don't want to have to add an unnecessary Test config to each class library which will be an exact copy of the Release config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working through exactly the same issue, unfortunately I don't see any other option but to add in the extra configurations. We are actually using the other configurations for our web.config substitution, a nice feature of VS2010.
It seems that it is not possible to have multiple configurations when running MSBuild.
I get the following in TeamCity:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(483,
>   9): The OutputPath property is not set for project 'something.csproj'.
>   Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
>   of Configuration and Platform for this project.
>   Configuration='SomeConfiguration' Platform='AnyCPU'. You may be
>   seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without
>   a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

Only our main website has the "SomeConfiguration" configuration, none of the constituent projects in the solution have this configuration.

It would be great to get another perspective on this

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity uses MSBuild.exe to build a solution. 
Does this work if start MSBuild.exe foo.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild from console?

Check you do not have a system.Configuration parameter in finished build parameters tab.